# Show images in quiz javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a quiz that tests users awareness of real and fake emails. What I want to do is have the question displayed at the top saying "Real or Fake", then have an image displayed underneath which the user needs to look at to decided if it's real or fake. There are two buttons, real and fake, and regardless of whether they choose the right answer I want to swap the original image with annotated version - showing how users could spot that it was fake or real.

But I'm not sure how to show the annotated version once the answer has been submitted. Could someone help?

```js
function Quiz(questions) {
  this.score = 0;
  this.questions = questions;
  this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
  return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
  if (this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
    this.score++;
  }

  this.questionIndex++;
}

Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
  return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}


function Question(text, choices, answer) {

  this.text = text;
  this.choices = choices;
  this.answer = answer;
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
  return this.answer === choice;
}


function populate() {
  if (quiz.isEnded()) {
    showScores();
  } else {
    // show question
    var element = document.getElementById("question");
    element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

    // show options
    var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
      var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
      element.innerHTML = choices[i];
      guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
    }

    showProgress();
  }
};

function guess(id, guess) {
  var button = document.getElementById(id);
  button.onclick = function() {
    quiz.guess(guess);
    populate();
  }
};


function showProgress() {
  var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
  var element = document.getElementById("progress");
  element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
};

function showScores() {
  var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
  gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
  var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
  element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
};

// create questions here
var questions = [
  new Question("<img src= 'netflix_fake.jpg' />", ["Real", "Fake"], "Fake"),
  new Question("<img src= 'dropbox_real.jpg' />", ["Real", "Fake"], "Real"),
  new Question("<img src= 'gov_real.jpg' />", ["Real", "Fake"], "Real"),
  new Question("<img src= 'paypal_fake.jpg' />", ["Real", "Fake"], "Fake"),
  new Question("<img src= 'gmail.jpg' />", ["Real", "Fake"], "Fake")
];

//create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

// display
populate();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #538a70;
}

.grid {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
  border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.grid h1 {
  font-family: "sans-serif";
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 2px 0px;
}

#score {
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.grid #question {
  font-family: "monospace";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000000;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#btn0,
#btn1,
#btn2,
#btn3 {
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #1D3C6A;
  margin: 10px 40px 10px 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

#btn0:hover,
#btn1:hover,
#btn2:hover,
#btn3:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #00994d;
}

#btn0:focus,
#btn1:focus,
#btn2:focus,
#btn3:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#progress {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="quiz">
    <h1>Can you spot the fake email?</h1>
    <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

    <p id="question"></p>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
      <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>

    </div>

    <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
    <footer>
      <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just put in array object

`const images = [{source: "image.link", fake: true},{source: "image.link", fake: false}]`

and then randomly generate it on page and after user clicks it, is it fake or true just check that with if else statement

Comment: Would you be able to show me what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When user clicks button I trigger class and I add it second name, on second I have written to get swapped, I wrote you basically full project, and please read the whole comments, to understand logic

```js
//Calling Elements from DOM
const button = document.querySelectorAll(".check");
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
const answer = document.querySelector("h1");

//Declaring variable to randomly insert any object there to insert source in DOM Image sources
let PreparedPhotos;

//Our Images Sources and With them are its fake or not
//fake: true - yes its fake
//fake: false - no its real
const image = [
    [
        {
            src:
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/1200px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg",
            fake: true
        },
        {
            src:
                "http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/04/13/world/europe/mona-lisa-like-new-images/mona-lisa-like-new-images-custom4-v3.jpg",
            fake: false
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            src:
                "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0849/4704/files/Creacion_de_Adan__Miguel_Angel_f5adb235-bfa8-4caa-8ffb-c5328cbad953_grande.jpg?12799626327330268216",
            fake: false
        },
        {
            src:
                "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0849/4704/files/First-image_Fb-size_grande.jpg?10773543754915177139",
            fake: true
        }
    ]
];

//Genrating Random Photo on HTML
function setRandomPhoto() {
  //Random Number which will be length of our array of Object
  //if you array includes 20 object it will generate random number
  // 0 - 19
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * image.length);

  //Decalaring our already set variable as Array Object
    PreparedPhoto = image[randomNumber];
  //Our first DOM Image is Variables first object source
    images[0].src = PreparedPhoto[0].src;
  //and next image is next object source
    images[1].src = PreparedPhoto[1].src;
}

//when windows successfully loads, up function runs
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    setRandomPhoto();
});

//buttons click
//forEach is High Order method, basically this is for Loop but when you want to 
//trigger click use forEach - (e) is single button whic will be clicked 
button.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //decalring variable before using it
        let filtered;

    //finding from our DOM image source if in our long array exists
    //same string or not as Image.src
    //if it exists filtered variable get declared with that found obect
        for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
            for (let k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                if (image[i][k].src === images[0].src) {
                    filtered = image[i][k];
                }
            }
        }
        
      //basic if else statement, if clicked button is Fake and image is true
    //it outputs You are correct
    //if clicked button is Real and Image is false it outputs Correct
    //Else its false
    
    //Our image checking comes from filtered variable
        if (e.innerText === "Fake" && filtered.fake === true) {
            
            answer.innerText = "You Are Correct";
            
            images.forEach((image) => {
                image.classList.toggle("hidden");
            });
        } else if (e.innerText === "Real" && filtered.fake === false) {
            answer.innerText = "You Are Correct";
            images.forEach((image) => {
                image.classList.toggle("hidden");
            });
            
        } else {
            answer.innerHTML = "You are Wrong";
  
            images.forEach((image) => {
                image.classList.toggle("hidden");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.image-fluid {
    display: flex;
}
.image-fluid .image {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.image-fluid .image:nth-child(1).hidden {
    transform: translateX(110px);
}
.image-fluid .image:nth-child(2).hidden {
    transform: translateX(-110px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-fluid">
        <img src="" class="image hidden">
        <img src="" class="image hidden">
    </div>
    <div class="button-fluid">
        <button class="check">Fake</button>
        <button class="check">Real</button>
    </div>
</div>

<h1></h1>
```

Comment: Does it answer your quoestion?

Comment: But I need it to actually change the original picture, for example the user is shown a picture, they then select real or fake and once selected real or fake it a swaps the original picture to an annotated version discussing how you can determine if it's real or fake. So after clicking check answer it reveals whether it's real or fake and swaps the image.

Comment: can you show me example? if you know website which is same as your idea

Comment: I just need to swap the image to another image when the user presses the Check Answer button.

Comment: I edited whole code please read it, I hope it will help you  :))